# Is this graph a tree and how do you reason it correctly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, directed-graphs

[image]

Is this graph a tree?

---

I'm not sure if my answer and especially my reasoning is correct?

A tree is an undirected graph where two arbitrary vertices are connected by exactly one path, e.g. a graph is a tree if it is acyclic and connected. A directed graph is a tree if its undirected form is a tree. So if we consider the graph as an undirected tree, we have that it's cyclic. As example, we have the path $(A,C,D,A)$. Since the undirected graph is not acyclic, it is not a tree. Since the undirected graph is not a tree, its directed form is not a tree. Thus the given directed graph above is not a tree.

Is my reasoning correct and is there an easier / better way to reason it?

Comment: Makes sense to me.

Comment: What could be simpler than appealing directly to the definition? A tree is acyclic, this graph (undirected form) has cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah your reasoning is correct, any graphs containing nodes with more than 1 parent are not trees because of undirected cycle.